# jQuery: How to change the size of a css block?

Tags: jquery, css

Working on an assignment, and I don't think this is the part we're supposed to be having trouble with (we're supposed to be working on scroll buttons, which I already have an idea on):

```
"--create a page that displays some paragraphs using the css block style. 
The block size should be too small to display the text in its entirety."
```

I've got a bunch of text in a div with id="story" and I have this inside my script tags:

```
$("#story").css("display", "block");
```

However nothing appears to change. The layout remains the same and I can't for the life of me figure out how to change the size of a css **block**. Everything I find is about box-size.

So two questions: 1. Why is the display not changing when I use .css() to apply 'block' and 2. how do you specify the size of a css block?

Edit:
I've tried adding:

```
$("#story").css("height", "20px");
```

but that also shows no change.

Edit:

Thank you all! Everyone was spot on and I feel incredibly silly. I didn't realize that overflow had to be set before it would apply the size setting. As soon as I put in:

```
overflow: scroll;
```

it started displaying correctly. Guess that's what I get for trying to put in one piece at a time

;p

Comment: Try setting a height that's smaller than the content. And both divs and paragraphs are block level by default.

Comment: what do you mean by change size of css block ? doesn't make any sense .. are you new to web development ?

Comment: Yeah, pretty new. And changing the size of a css block doesn't make any sense to me either, hence my question.      "create a page that displays some paragraphs using the css block style. The block size should be too small to display the text in its entirety. Disable the scroll bar from displaying next to the block.  "  Teachers words

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.css("display", "block")` displays an element as a block element. A div is displayed as block by default.

What you have to do is specify the height manually, either through CSS:

```
#story
{
    height: 100px;
}
```

Or if you want to use jQuery:

```
$("#story").css("height", "100px");
```

If you want to have it scrollable, add this to the CSS:

```
overflow-y: scroll;
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to explicity give a fixed `width` and `height` in your CSS.

Divs (and other elements with `display:block` applied) are fluid otherwise, and will expand to contain whatever is put in them.

Answer (score 1):

1. A "div" by default is displayed as a block.
2. You specify the size of a block with the width and height parameters.